# Не корректная отдача статического файла после изменения

Tags: nginx, vagrant

Использую vagrant. Ност: MacOS, гость: debian. На виртуальной машине установлен nginx 1.8.

После изменения статического файла (css или js) nginx отдает старый файл с добавленными какими-то символами.

Выглядит в браузере как-то так:

[image: Некорректная отдача файла nginx после изминения]

Пробовал изменять настройки nginx. sendfile, expires. Ничего не помогло. Выводил с помощью `cat` файл, выглядить вроде как нужно.

Что бы хоть как то работать, удаляю файл. Запрашиваю его снова, возвращается 404-я. Добавляю файл обратно. Запрашиваю - файл возвращается корректным.

Подскажите куда копать или как победить это.

Comment: *после изменения* ­— изменение состоит в удалении части информации из файла? в смысле: файл становится короче после изменения?

Comment: при добавлении в файл.

Comment: Что то я поигрался с уменьшение файла и после увеличения, проблема самоустранилась :\

Comment: может быть, проблема в браузере? wget-ом/curl-ом каким-нибудь скачайте, и посмотрите hexdump-ом.

Comment: точно такая же проблема
Mac os, vagrant 1.8, ubuntu trusty, nginx/1.4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение нашел [вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219578/nginx-and-css-issue)

```
## Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    sendfile off;
}
```